# AngularJS - regex not validated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have this input area on my HTML that gets a % value that should be validated.
The regex I have here has been tried also on regex101.com and should be working.

```
<script id="percAnswer" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="input-group" ng-if="vm.visibility(value)">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value.answer.numericValue" ng-disabled="value.question.readonly" ng-pattern="/^([1-9]{1,2}){1}(\,[0-9]{1,2})?$/" number-format decimals="2" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Don't know why, but only words aren't allowed. All numbers instead are accepted, positive and negative.

How could be that possible?

PS: I tried also to check some regex with decimals, but there was no way to fix this.

Comment: The ng-pattern looks ok to me... https://plnkr.co/edit/IZaEudEk5IlXtpXp9iae   I bet it's your 'number-format' directive causing the problem.

Comment: Corrected the regex. On the site works fine, but not in the code.

Comment: The number-format directive is probably doing its own, well, formatting of the number, which may be overriding your ng-pattern.

Comment: Yes, the regex looks good here is the plunkr I created: https://plnkr.co/edit/5g3qGH?p=preview